# How are multiple spaces showing in HTML, without pre, nbsp or white-space: pre?

Tags: html, css, text, tinymce, whitespace

I'm sure this shouldn't be possible. Somehow, multiple spaces within paragraphs in my HTML markup aren't collapsing. They are **not** `&nbsp;`, **not** in a `<pre>` tag, **not** set to `white-space: pre-wrap;` or `white-space: pre;` and the behaviour is **not** changed by forcing `style="white-space: normal;"` on the element.

My understanding is, that these are the only three ways that whitespace can be preserved and that two or more spaces can be made to show up in HTML.

So the question is: What else could cause sequential whitespace to show up as multiple spaces? There must be something else - but I can't look for it until I know what it is, and every source I find just talks about `&nbsp;`, `<pre>` and `white-space: pre-wrap;` or `white-space: pre;`

**Key edit:** Using Firebug I tried deleting some of the offending whitespace and typing it back in again. When deleted and re-entered from the keyboard, the spaces behave as normal - no unexpected whitespace in the browser. So it *must* be some character that shows up in view source, text editors, etc as a plain space, but actually behaves like `&nbsp;`. What can it be, and crucially, how can I identify it to remove it? The original source of the offending input is the wysiwyg editor TinyMCE so I'm adding that tag...

---

**More detail:** I have some HTML containing paragraph text that includes multiple spaces, like this (between the ...s is copied direct from Firefox view source):

```
<p> blah blah.... nothing  more  than  a ... blah blah </p>
```

As you can see, **these are regular spaces, not** `&nbsp;`. The document has `&nbsp;` elsewhere and they show up as such in view source, so they're not `&nbsp;`s somehow masquerading as normal spaces in the source.

Also, **the CSS is *not* set to** `white-space: pre;` or anything like that:

- Firebug's 'Computed' panel lists no whitespace related rules.
- Forcing a `white-space: normal;` on the paragraph makes no difference to the spaces. The rule does show up in the Firebug 'Computed' panel, so it is applying.
- Applying `white-space: pre-wrap;` to the paragraph results in other changes, but doesn't change these multiple sequencial spaces. For example, it makes an extra space visible at the end of each line break within a paragraph of selected text. So it's definitely not somehow being stealthily set to `white-space: pre-wrap;`

**There are no** `<pre>` **tags** in the document, anywhere. Find on `<pre` in the source finds nothing.

So it should therefore show in the browser with one space between each word. It  doesn't. It shows multiple spaces as if it was `<pre>` or `&nbsp;` or  `white-space: pre;`. But it isn't any of these.

There *must* be some other way of getting a  `white-space: pre;` like effect I don't know about. What other ways to preformat whitespace and stop multiple spaces collapsing are there? What could possibly be causing this.

---

A few background notes:

- **Seen in which browsers?** Firefox 16.0.2, Google Chrome 23.0.1271.95 m (Windows)
- **Why is there double spaced whitespace in the markup if you don't want it visible?** I'm working on the front end / design for a CMS where the users will be inputting text from Word and PDFs via TinyMCE wysiwyg (non-negotiable). Therefore, the markup will be messy. Fixing the CMS text formatter to scrub whitespace and clean the markup is outside the scope of this work.
- **Doctype?** `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML+RDFa 1.1//EN">`
- **You're sure there are multiple spaces?** Definitely, you can select one, two, in some cases three spaces between words in the browser front-end.
- **Can I seez all teh codez?** Sorry, but it's a pre-launch site, it's not publicly available. Feel free to ask about specific CSS rules, HTML tags, javascript stuff loaded etc etc.

Comment: This seems silly. If the HTML doesn't work as expected, it should take seconds to see what is going on. Show us an example. Give us a URL.

Comment: @user568458 can u put the text part in a jsfiddle?

Comment: @JonathanWood It sure does seem silly, but I already answered your comment in the original post. Those spaces in the blah blah bit are copied straight from view source, and I explained why I can't drop in a URL in the final bullet.

Comment: I would guess that these are not regular whitespaces. Maybe there are tabs which makes you think its several spaces but actually its effectively only one whitespace character.

Comment: @SajjanSarkar In principle yes, but regardless of whether I copy from the source or from the browser front end, after being input and processed by jsfiddle, they behave as normal. See also my edit - you're right that it's **definitely** something about the space character, but I can't think of a way to find out what the space character *really* is.

Comment: "it's a pre-launch site" isn't a good enough reason to not include a fiddle.  If the spaces are in the source, it isn't a CSS problem.

Comment: @Christoph First part correct, see new 'Key edit' paragraph, but they're not tabs. See 'You're sure they're multiple spaces?' bullet - each one is individually selectable

Comment: @cimmanon Downvote is a bit harsh considering I was typing up a fiddle while you wrote your comment...

Comment: @user568458 your accusations are misplaced.  But since you brought it up...

Comment: a simple `.replace(/\s*/g," ")` should fix this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing that the offending space characters in your source code are not [SPACE (U+0020)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0020/index.htm), but are actually [NO-BREAK SPACE (U+00A0)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm). Visually, they appear identical, but if you view your source code in a hex editor (which shows you the individual bytes in the file), you'll see a different encoding for these characters.

**Edit 1**

This PHP code should find and replace the offending characters with regular spaces:

```
$strNoBreakSpace = mb_convert_encoding('&#x00A0;', 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
$strNormalSpace  = mb_convert_encoding('&#x0020;', 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');

$strInput = str_replace( $strNoBreakSpace, $strNormalSpace, $strInput );
```

**Edit 2**

A simpler way of creating the two space characters:

```
$strNoBreakSpace = json_decode('"\u00A0"');
$strNormalSpace  = json_decode('"\u0020"');
```

Comment: Exactly right - the 'second spaces' from my text editor show as two . characters in http://www.onlinehexeditor.com  - 0xc2 followed by 0xa0 which according to http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=128&number=128&names=-&utf8=0x means unicode character point U+00A0. Thanks - I thought I was going mad (and judging by the many downvotes from non-unicode-fluent readers, other people clearly thought I was going mad too...)

Comment: The downvotes were unfair - you asked an excellent question and provided a great amount of info which really helped to narrow down the source of the problem.

Comment: Thanks :) This is StackOverflow, so I guess the downvotes were because the question had [not enough jQuery](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif) ;)